# C stats about file,

Tags: c, file

I wrote this code to read a file and to analyze it.

I used `fgets` to analyze it line by line and in this way I found:

- largest line in the file;
- total number of words;
- total number of lines.

In the last part I analyzed only the largest line to get:

- number of words of the largest line.

Thanks for your attention, I'll wait some hints and your help to find any error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    int i,parole,righe,paroleRiga;
    char c[102],ccont,lineaMax[102], filename;
    FILE * fp= fopen(filename,"r");

    if (fp==NULL)
        printf("errore di apertura");
    parole=righe=0;
    c=fgetc(fp);
    lineaMax={0}
    while(fgets(c,102,fp)!=NULL){
        puts(c);
        if(strlen(c)>strlen(lineaMax))
            strncpy(lineaMax,c,strlen(c));
        for (i=0;i<=strlen(c);i++)
            if (c[i]!=''&&c[i]!='\n')
                parole++;

    }
    righe++;
    fclose(fp);
    do{
        ccont=getc(lineaMax);
        if (ccont=='') paroleRiga++;

    }while(ccont!='\n')

    printf("numero di linee:%d,\n",righe)
    print("caratteri Tot:%d\n,Max:%d,Media:%d\n",parole,paroleRiga,(parole/righe)
    printf("\ntesto linea più lunga:%s",lineaMax);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: 1. What is the question? 2. It is not helpful to have non english variable names and text in your program. 3. There is at least one problem: if `fp` is `NULL` you display an error message but the program still continues and tries to read from a `NULL` file pointer.

Comment: There's a lot of error in that code, do you even try to compile it?: `filename` should be a `char[]` or `char*` and initialized, semicolons are missing, `getc()` is not used on a `FILE*`, the `print` function does not exists, `''` is not the rigth way to code a space character...

Comment: Downvoted and vote to close: the code has too many basic errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int i,
        parole = 0, //initialize variables here, its neater
        righe = 0,
        paroleRiga;
    char c[102], ccont, lineaMax[102] = "", *filename; //please initialize strings with strings. Btw, filename is never set
    FILE * fp= fopen(filename,"r");

    if (fp==NULL){
        printf("errore di apertura");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); //exit on failure
    }
    while(fgets(c,102,fp) != NULL){ // why 102
        puts(c);
        if(strlen(c) > strlen(lineaMax))
            strncpy(lineaMax,c,strlen(c));
        for (i=0;i<=strlen(c);i++)
            if (c[i]!=' '&&c[i]!='\n')
                parole++;

    }
    righe++;
    fclose(fp);
    do{
        ccont=getc(lineaMax);
        if (ccont==' ') paroleRiga++;

    } while(ccont!='\n');

    printf("numero di linee:%d,\n",righe); //righe is always 1 (0, ++)
    printf("caratteri Tot:%d\n,Max:%d,Media:%d\n",parole,paroleRiga,(parole/righe);
    printf("\ntesto linea più lunga:%s",lineaMax);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```